# PM2 not launching nodejs application on localhost

Tags: node.js, pm2

PM2 is not launching the application on the localhost. Without PM2 i start my application with npm start. i have tried pm2 start npm -- start but i get an unexpected token error in the logs.

$ pm2 logs

[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)

C:\Users\fssykes.pm2\pm2.log last 15 lines:

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:05: PM2 log: App [npm:7] online

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:05: PM2 log: App [npm:7] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:05: PM2 log: App [npm:7] starting in -fork mode-

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:05: PM2 log: App [npm:7] online

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] starting in -fork mode-

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] online

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] starting in -fork mode-

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] online

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] starting in -fork mode-

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] online

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: App [npm:7] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

PM2        | 2019-05-16T11:31:06: PM2 log: Script C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"

C:\Users\fssykes.pm2\logs\npm-out.log last 15 lines:

C:\Users\fssykes.pm2\logs\npm-error.log last 15 lines:

7|npm      | C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1

7|npm      | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.

7|npm      |                                                               ^

7|npm      |

7|npm      | SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

7|npm      |     at new Script (vm.js:80:7)

7|npm      |     at createScript (vm.js:274:10)

7|npm      |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)

7|npm      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)

7|npm      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)

7|npm      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)

7|npm      |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)

7|npm      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)

7|npm      |     at Function._load (C:\Users\fssykes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules@pm2\io\build\main\metrics\httpMetrics.js:172:43)

7|npm      |     at Object. (C:\Users\fssykes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)

Comment: 7|npm      | C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
7|npm      | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
7|npm      |                                                               ^
7|npm      |
7|npm      | SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: You can add useful content like that to the question with an edit where you have more control over formatting.

Comment: `npm start` what? Usually you run a specific command, not `npm` itself.

Comment: I gitbash into the app folder and enter npm start which will run app.js

Comment: I think `pm2` needs to know more about your application, so you may need to specify the full path to the JavaScript executable. That's how I've always used it.

Comment: @tadman6 can you show an example